# How to declare a row as a Alternate Row

Tags: sql, group-by

```
  id    Name    claim   priority 
   1    yatin   70      5         
   6    yatin   1       10        
   2    hiren   30      3         
   3    pankaj  40      2         
   4    kavin   50      1         
   5    jigo    10      4           
   7    jigo    1       10
```

this is my table and i want to arrange this table as shown below

```
  id    Name    claim   priority AlternateFlag
   1    yatin   70      5         0
   6    yatin   1       10        0
   2    hiren   30      3         1
   3    pankaj  40      2         0
   4    kavin   50      1         1
   5    jigo    10      4         0    
   7    jigo    1       10        0
```

It is sorted as alternate group of same row.

I am Using sql server 2005. Alternate flag starts with '0'. In my example First record with name "yatin" so set AlternateFlag as '0'.

Now second record has a same name as "yatin" so alternate flag would be '0'

Now Third record with name "hiren" is single record, so assign '1' to it

In short i want identify alternate group with same name...

Hope you understand my problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is the value for `AlternateFlag` calculated? Which database server are you using?

Comment: Not possible to give you an answer wihout knowing the way your Alternate flag is being calculated

Comment: I wonder if names are unique?

Answer (score 0):

You could use probably an aggregate function `COUNT()` and then `HAVING()` and then `UNION` both Table, like:

```
 SELECT id, A.Name, Claim, Priority, 0 as AlternateFlag
 FROM YourTable 
 INNER JOIN (
 SELECT Name, COUNT(*) as NameCount 
 FROM YourTable
 GROUP BY Name
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) A
 ON YourTable.Name = A.Name
 UNION ALL
 SELECT id, B.Name, Claim, Priority, 1 as AlternateFlag
 FROM YourTable 
 INNER JOIN (
 SELECT Name, COUNT(*) as NameCount 
 FROM YourTable
 GROUP BY Name
 HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 ) B
 ON YourTable.Name = B.Name
```

Now, this assumes that the Names are unique meaning the names like `Yatin` for example although has two counts is only associated to one person.

See my [SqlFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52c98/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT t.*, f.AlternateFlag
FROM tbl t
JOIN (
    SELECT [name], 
        AlternateFlag = ~CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MIN(ID)) % 2 AS BIT)
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY name
) f ON f.name = t.name
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/24601)

Answer (score -1):

You can use Row_Number() function with OVER that will give you enumeration, than use the reminder of integer division it by 2 - so you'll get 1s and 0s in your SELECT or in the view.

Comment: it will give you a alternate row but i want to make alternate group of same row...

Comment: @AijazChauhan then group by name (or only get distinct names), give 0s and 1s to every of them and then join result to the same table by result.name=table.name